# Without a delay, 'update' won't fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
 myTable()
            .update(data, {
                where: criteria
            })
            .then(delay(100))
            .then((entries) => {
            ...
            ...
```

The `.then(delay(100))` part sets a delay of 100ms.

If I don't use that delay, sometimes `entries` (the resulted updated rows) aren't correct, meaning their fields were not updated. But sometimes they are.

If I'm using the delay, the content of `entries` is always correct.

Why do I have to set a delay for it to work?

My local MySQL `my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql.log
general_log = 1
sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_log_file_size = 100M
interactive_timeout = 32000
lock_wait_timeout = 41536000
net_read_timeout = 120
net_write_timeout = 900
wait_timeout = 32000
max_allowed_packet = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
```

In terms of the table schema and model:
It has a few `double` columns, a couple of `datetime` and `char`, one `json` column and one `enum` column.
They are defined the same in the model.

Comment: What's your DB setup? At 1st glance, this looks like a caching issue.

Comment: So apparently, the then block resolves if the update action you're performing above is successful.

Hence, the delay being simulated isn't necessary.

The problem, therefore, is from the table you're querying. Can I see how you defined your table's schema and model? With that, the issue should be resolvable.

Comment: @Olumide i updated my post.

Comment: @Yoshimitsu i updated my post.

Comment: I would start by trying to do that update inside a transaction.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help :/

Comment: please post more code, mainly the `criteria`

Comment: The `criteria` is very simple like `where: {coulmn: value}`. There's no nesting or anything like that.

Comment: does this happens for all `UPDATE` statements or only this particular case?

Comment: why not just use setTimeout core function if you need delayed actions? I dont see any point in this one extra then clause.

Comment: @Khang: there are no others, only this one.

Comment: @JimiPajala: i don't want to use a delayed action, that's the whole point of this question i asked. I'm looking for an actual solution to this problem and not a "hack" like setting a delay.

Comment: Please check the isolation level on database

Comment: do you hv catch statment ? cuz I am thinking it is because of some errors it is not showing the updates.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check the isolation level on database

2) In general the [Transaction](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/transaction.js~Transaction.html)s may be what you need, if the issue with isolation level appears, try to select different isolation level for a transaction

3) cluster mode may result in such issues

Answer (score 0):

**So, the `.then(...` block is executed after the update promise is resolved.** And it does not have influence on the update query.

```
return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {

    // chain all your queries here. make sure you return them.
    return yourModel.update(updates,{where: { 'id': id } },
        {transaction: t}).then(function (entries) {
             // your logic with your entries.
      });

}).then(function (result) {
    // Transaction has been committed
    cb(null,result);
    console.log('transaction commited');
}).catch(function (err) {
    // Transaction has been rolled back
    cb(err,null);
    console.log('Transaction rolled back');
});
```

---

And if you are curious on what was happening when you add `.then(delay(100))...` statement use `catch` block because when you find the entries diffrenet from what you have expected it is because the query has already failed to update.